# ¿Cómo cambiar de nombre a un archivo php cuando se muestra en la url de la pagina?

Tags: html, .htaccess

Estoy utilizando rutas amigables, tengo el siguiente codigo en un achivo htaccess

```
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php`
```

Este código hace que en lugar de escribir usuarios.php, escribes usuarios/ y funciona

Pero lo que quiero es cambiar de nombre ejemplo:
En lugar de usuarios/ sea catalogo-usuarios y esta url seria el archivo usuarios.php

Como podría hacer eso, funciona con parámetro pero sin no se como implementarlo, alguna ayuda.!?

Este es mi codigo completo:

```
    Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Activar RewriteEngine
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /admonCapacitacion/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^admonCapacitacion/c/css.*$
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

 
#USUARIOS

RewriteRule ^usuarios/catalogo-usuarios$ usuarios/usuarios.php
RewriteRule ^usuarios/catalogo-usuarios\/$ usuarios/usuarios.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

</IfModule>
```

Cabe aclarar que mi archivo usuarios.php esta dentro de una carpeta en raíz llamada usuarios

Comment: Te refieres a hardcodearlo solo para ese caso?  así?  `RewriteRule ^catalogo-usuarios$ usuarios.php` (bueno, metele la barra tambien si quieres a la primera parte).  Si lo haces procura que esta rule este antes de la otra más generica pues sino no llegará a ejecutarse nunca

Answer (score 0):

Respuesta editada:
Dados los nuevos datos (el .htaccess completo), y presuponiendo que el archivo .htaccess está en la carpeta raiz `/` diria que la solución es esta:

```
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Activar RewriteEngine
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /admonCapacitacion/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^admonCapacitacion/c/css.*$
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
#USUARIOS
RewriteRule ^admonCapacitacion/usuarios/catalogo-usuarios$ usuarios/usuarios.php 
RewriteRule ^admonCapacitacion/usuarios/catalogo-usuarios/$ usuarios/usuarios.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
</IfModule>
```

Fijarse que el `RewriteBase` está apuntando al directorio  `/admonCapacitacion/` y que ese valor **solo** va a usarse en la segunda parte de un RewriteRule, es decir, en `usuarios/usuarios.php` pero no en la primera, por lo tanto en la primera si que debemos poner la ruta completa así `^admonCapacitacion/usuarios/catalogo-usuarios$`.

Sin embargo, si el `.htaccess` está en la carpeta `/admonCapacitacion/` entonces deberia ser así:

```
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Activar RewriteEngine
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^admonCapacitacion/c/css.*$
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
#USUARIOS
RewriteRule ^usuarios/catalogo-usuarios$ usuarios/usuarios.php 
RewriteRule ^usuarios/catalogo-usuarios/$ usuarios/usuarios.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
</IfModule>
```

En este caso he eliminado el `RewriteBase` y tambien la ruta de la carpeta en la primera parte de las `RewriteRule`.

---

Respuesta anterior (solo de referencia, ya no es válida, será eliminada cuando la respuesta sea la correcta)

<s>Si te refieres a solo tener en cuenta este caso concreto y dejar la rule inicial intacta entonces debes agregar esta linea antes de la actual, así:</s>

```
RewriteRule ^catalogo-usuarios$ /usuarios.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Procura que el `RewriteEngine on` esté activado por encima de estas lineas para que funcione bien.

Si lo deseas con barra seria algo así:

```
RewriteRule ^catalogo-usuarios\/$ /usuarios.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Si deseas ambos entonces así:

```
RewriteRule ^catalogo-usuarios$ /usuarios.php
RewriteRule ^catalogo-usuarios\/$ /usuarios.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

En fin, lo que desees :-)

Comment: Ya lo probe, pero me da error 404, actualice mi pregunta con mi codigo completo, crees que le puedas echar un vistazo? de favor

Comment: Prueba con `RewriteRule ^usuarios/catalogo-usuarios$ /usuarios/usuarios.php` o con `RewriteRule ^usuarios/catalogo-usuarios$ /admonCapacitacion/usuarios/usuarios.php`... a ver cual de los dos es... uno de ellos deberia funcionar... y me lo dices y actualizo la respuesta

Comment: A ver, por si acaso, primero dime la url completa que quieres que funcione... ¿seria esta?  `https://dominio.com/usuarios/catalogo-usuarios` ¿o más bien esta? `https://dominio.com/catalogo-usuarios`

Comment: La url es esta http://localhost:8080/admonCapacitacion/usuarios/catalogo-usuarios es la que quiero

Comment: Entonces deberia ser asi:  `RewriteRule ^admonCapacitacion/usuarios/catalogo-usuarios$ /admonCapacitacion/usuarios/usuarios.php` seguramente (si es que usuarios.php esta en esa ruta dentro de tu servidor web)

Comment: si pongo al final una diagonal, me manda error Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request., pero si la quito me manda 404

Comment: Vale, pues omite la barra invertida `\\` funcionara igual, era solo por si acaso pues en segun que servidores si que es necesaria para escapar el siguiente caracter

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132673/discussion-between-masterguru-and-luis-alberto).